# How to replace `link` function to target DOM element in Angular 2 component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular, angular2-directives

Link function in an Angular 1 [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) makes it possible to target DOM elements, via

```
link: function (scope, element, attr) {
    // do something with element[0], e.g. put generated graphics
    // inside the node
}
```

What's a replacement for that in Angular 2?

Comment: There is nothing like `link` what do you actually try to accomplish? For concrete examples it's easier to tell how it's done in Angular2.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm trying to attach a JS generated graphic inside the container node, e.g. `var graph2d = new vis.Graph2d(container, dataset, options);`

Comment: Hmm, what is `graph2d`? An HTML element?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `graph2d` is a `vis.Graph2d` instance. It doesn't really matter what it is. The library expects a node as a container. The link function can provide such a node via e.g. `vis.Graph2d(element[0]...` and I'm looking for the same capability in Angular 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
@Component({ 
...,
  template: `
  <div #target></div>
`
})
class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('target') target;

  // lifecycle callback when `this.target` becomes available
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var graph2d = new vis.Graph2d(
        this.target.nativeElement, dataset, options);
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't target the element itself, rather it targets its child. Would `private _el:HTMLElement; constructor(el: ElementRef) { this._el = el.nativeElement; }` make it possible to target the element directly?

Comment: Exactly, if you want to target the host element directly then the `ElementRef` injected by the constructor can be used. A shorter form with the same effect would be `constructor(private el:ElementRef) {}`